# Why am I getting : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL here

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have this simple script:

```
    ids="22656"
    url = "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/"+ids+"/timeline";
    console.log( url );
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open(“GET”, url ,true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
            console.log( xmlhttp.responseText );
        }
        xmlhttp.send( null );
    };
```

But I don't quite understand why I'm getting:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Well xmlhttp to a different domain than your own ... is not going to work anyway.  Where do you see that error, and when?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The quotes around GET are not proper. You must use standard single or double quotes for strings.

Comment: :-O  ... awesome!!! I never realized that I had different quotes. I copied from a webpage, probably the html rendering change them. Now I'm getting `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` but I guess that's what @Pointy is referring to.